# Can't delete Google Font from Windows 10

Tags: fonts, windows-10

I have installed Roboto using Google fonts on Windows 10 and I can't figure out how to remove this font? The Unistall button is missing??

[Missing Unistall Button Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKXtS.png)